# PHP form including an extra quotation mark in the variable name

Tags: php, html

I have a slightly strange error (shown below)

[image]

This is the code in my login.php file

```
        <form action="loginScript.php" method="post">
            <input class="center" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <br>
            <input class="center" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <br>
            <input class="center" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

My loginScript.php file uses `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: The form you have shown here, definitively does not submit the field like that. Easily proven by https://jsfiddle.net/je7bkzwn/, and checking what it sends via browser dev tools, network panel. Suggest you do the same thing, to first of all verify whether the data does already get sent like that in your case - or if it must get manipulated at some later point.

Answer (score 1):

Remove name="username" and retype it. Did you copy and paste the code from somewhere? Probably your editor does not show hidden special characters.

Comment: I tried retyping it. I think the code was generated by GitHub Copilot.